# How to send request query string from html?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

I am new to ASP.Net . I have created a blog , the post page displays all the post by using XSLT to transform the xml data of the blog. However, I am struggling to create a dedicated post page whenever user click on the desired article.

[image]

This is the xslt code to transform the xml data of the blog post to the home :

```
<xsl:for-each select="Posts/post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        <div class="post-preview">
          <a href="Post.aspx">
            <h2 class="post-title">
              <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </h2>
            <h3 class="post-subtitle">
              <xsl:value-of select="subtitle"/>
            </h3>
          </a>
          <p class="post-meta">
            Posted by
            <xsl:value-of select="author"></xsl:value-of>
            on <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
          </p>

        </div>
        <hr/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>>
```

This is the post page I want it to be when user click on the desired article :

[image]

However, I have hard time getting the response query string with the code I have setup in the page_load of post page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["pid"] != null) { }
    XmlDocument xml_doc = new XmlDocument();
    postdata.DocumentSource = "~/Data/blog_post.xml";
    postdata.TransformSource = "~/XSLT file/ViewCurrentPost.xslt";
    System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList xslArg = new System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList();
    xslArg.AddParam("_pid", "", Request.QueryString["pid"]);
    postdata.TransformArgumentList = xslArg;

    xml_doc.Load(MapPath("~/blog_posts.xml"));
}
```

This is the XSL file I have made in order to display the correct post :

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Posts/post"/>
    <xsl:for-each select ="Posts/post">
      <xsl:if test="@pid=$_pid">
        <!--Header-->
        <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('img/post-bg.jpg')">
          <div class="overlay"></div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="post-heading">
                  <h1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                  </h1>
                  <h2 class="subheading">
                    <xsl:value-of select="subtitle"/>
                  </h2>
                  <span class="meta">
                    Posted by
                    <xsl:value-of select="author"></xsl:value-of>
                    on <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
```

This is my blog post structure :

```
<Posts>
<post pid="pid2623">
    <title>Test</title>
    <description>Test</description>
    <subtitle>Test</subtitle>
    <date>7/29/2018 12:00:00 AM</date>
    <author>est</author>
  </post>
<Posts>
```

Comment: It sounds as if you simply want to change `<a href="Post.aspx">` to `<a href="Post.aspx?pid={@pid}">`. I am not sure whether the use of both `<xsl:apply-templates select="Posts/post"/>` and `<xsl:for-each select ="Posts/post">` in the same XSLT makes any sense but that might then be a follow-up topic for a separate question once you have the ASPX code receiving the post id in the query string.

Comment: @MartinHonnen It works , I have received the response query string. Thank you for the hint :)